# Comparing two models in R

Tags: r

I'm using R to develop regression models, and I need to compare two different models' performance. The question that arises is, "Is Model 1 statistically better than model 2?" and I don't seem to have a way to answer that question.

Background: Model 1 consists of Variable A regressed on the endpoint. Model 2 consists of Variables B, C, and D regressed on the endpoint. Both models are developed using lm - ordinary least squares, nothing too fancy here.

Given that these are not nested models, I cannot compare them using ANOVA.

I can look at the R2 of actual vs predicted for each model, and I see that Model 2 is better, but how do I determine if it is statistically significantly better?

I've also used the Concordance Correlation Coefficient, but again, I can't find a way to prove significance. The best I've come up with is that the rho for Model 2 is better than Model 1, but that rho value is within the 95% confidence limits of the rho for Model 1.

I should throw in there that my assessment of predicted vs actual has been on a 60 observation hold-out set (240 observations in the training set).

Comment: Have you already thought of using Akaike's Information Criterion (AIC) or Mallows' $C_p$? Tests are a little tricky -  as you say, the models are non-nested - but in any case there's not necessarily any reason to take one model rather than the other as the null hypothesis.

Comment: You need to look at R2 adjusted, not just R2, since you are estimating models with a different number of parameters.  That said, I would argue that "Is Model 1 statistically better than model 2?" is too vague of a statement--- what is "better"? Less residual sum of squares? Does R2 really tell you which is "better"? What does the domain science say? Have you checked that both meet assumptions of OLS linear regression? I would use AIC to compare the candidate models, but there is no associated tests, only rule of thumbs. Perhaps look at the cox test (in the lmtest package of r)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I was afraid that might be the case.  What about my use of the Concordance Correlation Coefficient?  In this case I've used CCC to measure each model's departure from the diagonal line for its predicted vs. actual values - this seems better than just r2.  As I mentioned, I get a better rho for one of the models, but the 95% confidence intervals on those estimates are not disjoint.  My interpretation is that one model predicts better, but not with 95% confidence.

Comment: @KirkDCO: Same thing - you need to take the number of parameters into account. You could cross-validate & adjust it for optimism bias.

Comment: @TaylerJones: Wise comment (worth making into an answer). But a model's AIC is an estimate of its Kullback-Leibler divergence from the  true model; choosing the model with the lesser is not a test, true, but nor is it just a rule of thumb.

Comment: @Scortchi: Any directions of adjusting for optimism bias?  I assume I could follow the adjusted R2 approach, but I would rather ask than just assume I know how to get there.

Comment: @Scortchi - valid point about not just being a rule of thumb.

Comment: @KirkDCO have you checked your independent variables for multicollinearity? In particular if there is correlation between A and B, C, and/or D.

Comment: In the real world problem, there is some degree of colinearity in the variables.  I can mitigate that to some degree through variable selection, but I still end up with the same problem of comparing non-nested models.

Comment: When you say 'statistically better' ... what do you actually mean? How you answer that question may lead to potentially quite different kinds of answers.

Comment: @Glen_b:  Good question, albeit hard to answer.  Let me shine a bit more light on the subject.  Model A is the current best known model that is accepted, while Model BCD is more of an exploratory model.  Model A has some issues - this is in the medical domain, so I'll hold off on the details, but consider Model A difficult to obtain and somewhat invasive.

Comment: @Glen_b (continued):  Finding a new model would be a big help for this domain, and my Model BCD appears just as good if we compare R2, adjR2, and CCC rho on an external test set.  In presenting these results, the question came up as, "Given the confidence in Model A [presumably 95% confidence], is Model BCD statistically as good or better than Model A?"  I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm still not really any clearer on what 'statistically better' might mean.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase the question - how can I determine that one model is better than the other with some degree of statistical confidence?  Or, can I say that one model is better than the other and assign a p-value to that assertion?

Comment: If you need a test & p-value, what's wrong with the Cox test that @TaylerJones suggested?

Comment: @Scortchi:  Nothing wrong with that suggestion - just haven't been able to try it yet...

Comment: When I said tests would be tricky I was thinking of [Cox's 1959 paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200512162) but [Davidson & Mackinnon (1981)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1911522) have developed a simple procedure which is asymptotically equivalent to Cox's original test. I haven't tried it (I didn't know about it until reading @TaylerJones' comment) but it sounds like it's what you're asking for. Bear in mind that you need to define a null hypothesis that one of the models is true - this asymmetry, & that neither may be true, is perhaps why the test isn't commonly used.

Comment: @KirkDCO you need to rephrase your question in a way that doesn't use the word better (or a synonym thereof); Speak in statistical terms. The word "better" has no meaning in statistics.

Comment: @TaylerJones:  OK...how can I determine that the two models are different in their ability to predict, and can I assign a p-value to the assertion that the models are different with accuracy rates being higher or lower in one versus the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at the adjusted $R^2$, not just $R^2$, since you are estimating models with a different number of parameters.

That said, I would argue that "Is Model 1 statistically better than Model 2?" is too vague a statement—what is "better"? A lower residual sum of squares? Does $R^2$ really tell you which is "better"? What does the domain science say? Have you checked that both meet assumptions of OLS linear regression?

Remember George Box's famous words "All models are wrong, but some are useful." Which model would be most useful in your circumstances?  In every field of science, simple models are often the most powerful for description, whereas a more complicated model may give better predictions (assuming due diligence in preventing overfit has been performed).

I would use AIC to compare the candidate models, but there are no associated tests.
Perhaps consider the Cox test (in the `lmtest` package of R). There is nothing wrong with choosing the lower adjusted $R^2$, but again, this is heuristic in nature. If you wanted to really do it right, you should collect a testing set of data to validate the models and see which is more accurate in real world prediction.

You should also consider collinearity. If B, C and/or D have significant correlation structure, the second model is <s>invalid</s>**EDIT:** as per Scortchi's comment, the model is still valid, but standard errors will increase drastically. I would still consider a correlation structure between B,C,D as evidence towards the first model having more utility under *most* use cases. **/EDIT** Furthermore, if A is collinear with B, C, and/or D, it gives reason to believe A is a latent variable being measured by B, C, and/or D; in which case the first model is probably a better choice. Would be interested to see if you have attempted a regression model with A as the dependent variable and B, C, and D as predictors.

Overall, you should view model selection as an "art", rather than look for a process to give you a p-value on which is best.

Comment: If B, C, & D are nearly collinear the second model is still valid, i.e. coefficient estimates are still best linear unbiased, though their standard errors will be painfully large.

Comment: Good point, updated my answer.